# Android Exo Player continue the Playback where the user left off

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How to add Android Exo Player continue the Playback where the user left off?
Need Code Support

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Sorry for my bad Language

Comment: why don't you save its duration or time when the use left the screen and then resume it when user comes to screen?

Answer (score 1):

Store the duration at which user closes this activity against the content Id in db. On reopening, check if there is any entry present and then seekTo that duration.

Answer (score 0):

you can save duration while releasing the player in on pause and you can either store it locally or in server for that particular content.